# How to terminate a Web worker inside addEventListener()?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a Web Worker here.

`//worker.js
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
     self.postMessage(event.data);
     self.close();
  });`

And here main js file.

`//main.js
var webworker = new Worker("worker.js");
webworker.postMessage('Send something.');
webworker.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   webworker.terminate();
});`

The problem is that the "webworker.terminate();" inside the addEventListener does n't seem to work.There were no warnings or errors, but the web worker was not terminated.

I am creating an autocomplete input, it creates workers every typing, i use workers to search through a large data for the results, the problem that too many workers were created that i want to terminate them. i know they are still running because of the cpu consumed percentage and the code after "webworker.terminate();" still proceed while they should not. 
I simplize the code here, i create 8 workers for each typings in the input field, they work with the input value every types.The problem is that the old workers are still active while i type new value into the input field, i just want to terminate them.

```
inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {     
  
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  
        var webworker = new Worker("autocomplete/worker.js");
        
        webworker.postMessage(inp.value);
        
        webworker.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        //do thing
   })
 }
}
```

Is there a way to terminate the Web worker in this scenario?
 I just want to terminate the Worker right after the response's arrival. 
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Stack overflow pro-tip: never *ever* say "it doesn't work". Consider an example: "I wrote a function that adds two numbers but it doesn't work". That could mean it throws an exception, or gives the wrong answer, or doesn't compile, or goes into an infinite loop, or it works but the user is brand new and doesn't realize the output doesn't automatically print when you're not in the REPL. How are we supposed to know what "doesn't work" means? What do you *mean* by it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i have just edited the problem.

Comment: First, this is a very bad idea to kill your Worker after a single use  A Worker is very heavy, it brings a full JS context, a full event loop and uses a lot of memory. You should never have to terminate it yourself. Instead make it handle multiple tasks. Having it do nothing for some times will cost less than killing it and create a new one. Now to the question, how do you check if the Worker was correctly terminated?

Comment: i am creating an autocomplete input, it creates workers every typing, i use workers to search through a large data for the results, the problem that too many workers were created that i want to terminate them. i know they are still running because of the cpu consumed percentage and the code after "webworker.terminate();" still proceed while they should not.

Comment: Please show the "*it creates workers every typing*" code. I have a suspicion the closure over the `webworker` variable might be your problem. Apart from that: why do you terminate the worker when it sent a message? The worker could just do that on its own, and in fact it even does it: `self.close()`. Rather you'd terminate them when something else happens, e.g. the next input event from your input element. Either way, Kaiido is right your usage pattern of workers is problematic.

Comment: i edited my post, do you have any solutions to this problem.

Comment: Please show the actual code that you have a problem with, not some "simplized" version. Creating 8 workers, with the same source, on every input event, and sending them the same message, just makes no sense.

Comment: i don't think that the code is relevant here. I just want to know if the is a way to terminate the workers inside the addEventListener function because when i try, it could n't.

Comment: Browsers have only one thread for workers. Creating more than one worker of the same type lead to major performance issue. Please just use one worker and don't terminate it.

Comment: `.terminate()` must kill the worker. If it doesn't it's either you incorrectly checking if it's terminated or a bug in the browser.

Comment: It is entirely possibly that the underlying implementation is using pooling for the workers, meaning that the worker *is* terminated but the resources are put back in the pool rather than freed. Would also echo the others here: creating multiple workers is almost always a bad idea, and for your particular use case (autocomplete) using a worker is a bad idea *period*. You need to to be fast, and webworkers are not fast (communication overhead, resource usage overhead). Besides, what else is your main thread doing while the user is typing that you need to move work off of it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski "*Browsers have only one thread for workers*" - do you have a source for that?

Comment: thank you guys all for the advices and suggestions, the problem was more or less solved by changing 'var webwoker' to 'let webworker' or 'const webworker'.

Comment: Another reason to never use `var`